# Windows 11 takes very long to wake from sleep

Tags: windows, performance, sleep, windows-11

After entering sleep mode, my brand new PC takes **exactly 28 seconds** to show the login screen every time.

Configuration:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 12700K
- Motherboard: Asus TUF Gaming Z690 D4 Wifi
- SSD: Samsung 980 PRO
- OS: Windows 11 21H2

During wakeup, the following entry is written to system log (Event Viewer / Windows Logs / System, Source = Kernel-Power):

```
Firmware S3 times. ResumeCount: 1, FullResume: 18183, AverageResume: 18183
Firmware S3 times. SuspendStart: 98877, SuspendEnd: 98882
```

Every time `FullResume` takes 18 seconds. No errors or warnings around.

Here is the output for `powercfg`:

```
C:\Users\myuser>powercfg /availablesleepstates
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
    Hibernate
    Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Hybrid Sleep
        The hypervisor does not support this standby state.
```

I tried pretty much every advice I have found (to no avail):

- Updated Windows to latest version
- Updated BIOS and Intel ME firmware
- Installed drivers for all unknown devices (except for a RAID controller which I don't use and which is disabled in Device Manager)
- Turned "Fast boot" on and off in Power Options
- Uninstalled WSL from "Turn Windows features on or off"
- Removed various services from startup
- Ran various power-related troubleshooters provided by Windows
- Unplugged every USB device

What am I missing?

**UPD 1**: A strange thing which may or may not be relevant:

My RAM is Kingston HyperX Fury 2x16GB 3600 Mhz (HX436C18FB4K2/32). It has 2 XMP profiles: `3606` and `3000`.

Setting the first profile in BIOS prevents the system from starting up at all: PC restarts a few times in a row before booting, then defaults to 2133 MHz.

Setting the second profile apparently works, but the system is unstable. Complete freezes and BSODs with `Stop Code: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` happen several times per day. In this profile, the PC does not come back from sleep at all: it starts working but the screen never turns on.

Comment: I'll watch this.  Lenovo X230 Windows 11 Pro latest version. Put to sleep. 15 seconds to login screen. So it looks normal what you see.

Comment: Is it also this long when you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: @John a friend of mine bought pretty much the same config (SSD, motherboard, and i9 instead of i7) - his PC wakes up in 13 seconds (twice as fast), `Firmware S3 times` is 3000-ish (6 times as fast). Something's not right...

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to Delete any and all power plans except for the default power plan called Balanced. Then reset Balanced to default. Restart and test and only adjust Balanced after testing.

Comment: is his SSD M.2 ?

Comment: @harrymc cold startup time does not change between normal and safe mode. Windows doesn't let putting computer to sleep in safe mode though...

Comment: Try to delete the Display adaptors in Device Manager then reboot, allowing Windows to reinstall them. The screen should flicker and come back after the delete, but just in case, test shutting down by blindly entering Alt-F4 & Enter.

Comment: @John I restored the "Balanced" plan to defaults, no result. Two other plans are system defaults and apparently cannot be removed.

Comment: I don't know. In major brands, Balanced is the only remaining plan (Windows 10 and 11). I can only suggest now contacting ASUS Support.

Comment: Update: described a weird RAM issue which may be relevant.

Comment: Run a full set of hardware tests using the ASUS hardware test APP.

Comment: Is this issue specific to Windows 11? If you had Windows 10 on the new PC, how long did that take to wake? If it came with v. 11, I'd hesitate to install 10 over it, though. You might compare with sleep time from another OS, e.g. put Ubuntu on USB and run from that. Using HDD, not SSD, it takes about 7 seconds to resume.

Comment: For RAM problems, running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight is a good test.

Comment: @John it's a custom built desktop PC, not a notebook. MyAsus app only provides links to their knowledgebase, but no hardware testing mode.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I installed Win11 from scratch. A complete reinstall with Windows10 might be a solution, but it's gonna take a lot of time to set everything back up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this was caused by an Asus ThunderboltEX 4 card. Removing it immediately reduced the time from 28 to 12 seconds, and the log is as follows:

```
Firmware S3 times. ResumeCount: 1, FullResume: 2998, AverageResume: 2998
```

Why exactly this happens is still a mystery, and I will have to contact Asus support for clarifications.